# Unable to break infinite loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop, infinite-loop, break

There are various posts related to infinite loops on here but none reflect my particular predicament (they deal with Java or they do not match my code format etc). The code I have used is actually source code or 'answer code' to an exercise aimed at new students such as myself and it only supplies the 'correct code without correct format' which for an independent student can complicate things but also provide a more productive challenge.

The code makes solid use of 'functions' and 'calling functions from within other functions' which leaves very little 'global code' as a result, this may make things slightly more complicated but hopefully experienced programmers won't be phased by this.

I think the loop is either an issue with my 'while loop code indentation' or the 'while loop condition/counter code itself'. The loop code takes and uses data from other parts of the program code and shouldn't be completely ruled out but realistically I suspect the problem is one of the two former possible issues of either indentation or internal loop code itself, I have already tried multiple variations of 'indentation layout' as well as making quick fixes (misstyped syntax etc).

The code in question can be found towards the end of the program code (there is only one 'while loop' in the program code) it is in the 'menu options' section of code under '# Loop through quotes selecting those referencing the appropriate month and store the data in the summary dictionary'.

I have included two separate code windows, one highlighting the suspected 'problem code' and the the other with 'full program code'. Any help in any aspect will be appreciated.

Code segment most likely to hold error

```
def monthlyReport():
    file = open(QUOTES_TO_DATE_FILE, 'r')

    text = file.read()

    file.close()

    quotes = text.split()

    month = input('Enter month: ')

    summary = {'Lawn':{'Quantity' : 0.0, 'Value' : 0.0}, 'Patio' :{'Quantity' : 0.0, 'Value' : 0.0}, 'Water Feature' :{'Quantity' : 0.0, 'Value' : 0.0}}
# Loop through quotes selecting those referencing the appropriate month and
#store the data in summary dictionary
    index = 0

    while True:

    if quotes[index] == month:

            inputQuotesFromFile2(quotes[index+1])    

            summary['Lawn']['Quantity'] = summary['Lawn']['Quantity'] + quote['Lawn']['Width'] * quote['Lawn']['Length']

            summary['Lawn']['Value'] = summary['Lawn']['Value'] + quote ['Lawn']['Cost']

            summary['Patio']['Quantity'] = summary['Patio']['Quantity'] + quote['Patio']['Width'] * quote['Patio']['Length']

            summary['Patio']['Value'] = summary['Patio']['Value'] + quote['Patio']['Cost']

            summary['Water Feature']['Quantity'] = summary['Water Feature']['Quantity'] + quote['Water Feature']['Quantity']

            summary['Water Feature']['Value'] = summary['Water Feature']['Value'] + quote['Water Feature']['Cost']

            index = index + 2

        if (index >= len(quotes)):

            break

        totalValue = summary['Lawn']['Value'] + summary['Patio']['Value'] + summary['Water Feature']['Value']

        outputSummaryDictionary(summary, month, totalValue)
```

Full program code

```
# `Dictionary containing time values (mins) per square metre/ per feature
##lawn:20   patio:20  water feature:60
TIME = {'Lawn': 20, 'Patio': 20, 'Water Feature': 60}

# Constant for labour cost
##16.49
LABOUR_COST = 16.49

# Variable for filename of list of quotes made to date
##quotesToDateFile
QUOTES_TO_DATE_FILE = 'quotesToDateFile.txt'



# 'Global variables'

# A dictionary that stores quote data temporarily, contains sub dicts for each
#material type including keys for length, width, cost, time/quantity,cost, time
quote = {'Lawn':{'Length': 0 , 'Width': 0 , 'Cost': 0.0 , 'Time': 0.0},
         'Patio':{'Length': 0 , 'Width': 0, 'Cost': 0.0 , 'Time': 0.0 },
         'Water Feature':{'Quantity': 0 , 'Cost': 0.0 , 'Time': 0.0}}

# A dictionary storing material costs of individual items (can be updated)
materialCost = {'Lawn': 15.5, 'Patio': 20.99, 'Water Feature': 150}


# 'Input'

# Function to input material info defined by a length
##create function with named parameter for 'item'
def inputItemDimensions(item):

    s = 'Enter length of ' + item + ':'

    length = int(input('Enter length of material: '))

    s = 'Enter width of ' + item + ':'

    width = int(input('Enter width of material: '))

    return length, width

# Function to input material info defined by quantity
##create function with named parameter 'item
def inputItemQuantity(item):

    s = 'Enter quantity of ' + item + ':'

    quantity = int(input('Enter quantity of items: '))

    return quantity

# Function for input of area and quantity
def itemInput():

    global quote

    quote['Lawn']['Length'], quote['Lawn']['Width'] = inputItemDimensions('lawn')

    quote['Patio']['Length'], quote['Patio']['Width'] = inputItemDimensions('concrete patio')

    quote['Water Feature']['Quantity'] = inputItemQuantity('water feature')



# 'Cost calculation'

# Function to calculate, output to screen, return the material cost and time
#to install a landscape item installed by length and width
def costCalculation1(num, item, length, width, cost, time):

    print('[{0}]'.format(num))

    print('Length and width of the {0} = {1} x {2}m'.format(item, length, width))

    area = length * width

    print('Total area of {0} = {1:.2f}m^2'.format(item, area))


    print('Cost of {0} per m^2 = £{1:.2f}'.format(item, cost)) 


    totalCost = area * cost 

    print('Total cost of {0} = £{1}\n'.format(item, totalCost))

    totalTime = area * time

    return totalCost, totalTime

# Function to calculate, output to screen and return the material cost and time
#to install a landscape item installed by quantity
def costCalculation2(num, item, quantity, cost, time):

    print('[{0}]'.format(num))

    print('Quantity of {0} = {1} items'.format(item, quantity))

    print('Cost of one {0} = £{1:.2f}'.format(item, cost))

    totalCost = quantity * cost 

    print("Total cost of {0} {1} = £{2}\n".format(quantity, item, totalCost))

    totalTime = quantity * time

    return totalCost, totalTime

# Function to calculate individual costs of items
def calculateItemCosts():

    global quote

    quote['Lawn']['Cost'], quote['Lawn']['Time'] = costCalculation1('1', 'lawn', quote['Lawn']['Length'], quote['Lawn']['Width'], materialCost['Lawn'], TIME['Lawn'])

    quote['Patio']['Cost'], quote['Patio']['Time'] = costCalculation1('2', 'patio', quote['Patio']['Length'], quote['Patio']['Width'], materialCost['Patio'], TIME['Patio'])

    quote['Water Feature']['Cost'], quote['Water Feature']['Time'] = costCalculation2('3', 'water features', quote['Water Feature']['Quantity'], materialCost['Water Feature'], TIME['Water Feature'])


# Function to calculate workimg costs and output them
def workingCost():

    print('Working costs:')

    totalTime = (quote['Lawn']['Time'] + quote['Patio']['Time'] + quote['Water Feature']['Time']) / 60

    labourCost = totalTime * LABOUR_COST

    print('Total time to complete work = {0} mins'.format(totalTime))

    print('Cost of work per hour = £{0}'.format(LABOUR_COST)) 

    print('Total cost of work = £{0}\n'.format(labourCost))

# Calculate total fee payable by customer, output to screen and file
    materialCost = quote['Lawn']['Cost'] + quote['Patio']['Cost'] + quote['Water Feature']['Cost']

    totalCost = materialCost + labourCost

    print('Total cost to pay = £{0}\n'.format(totalCost))


# 'Output functions'

# Output details concerning item
def outputItems():

    outputItems1('1', 'Lawn', quote['Lawn'])

    outputItems1('2', 'Patio', quote['Patio'])

    outputItems2('3', 'Water Feature', quote['Water Feature'])


# Output dimensions and cost for certain item

def outputItems1(num, item, itemDict):

    print('[{0}]'.format(num))

    print('Length of width of {0} = {1}m x {2}m'.format(item, itemDict['Length'], itemDict['Width']))

    print('Total cost of {0} = £{1}'.format(item, itemDict['Cost']))

    print('Time to install {0} = {1}mins\n'.format(item, itemDict['Time'] / 60))

# Output quantity and cost for item

def outputItems2(num, item, itemDict):

    print('[{0}]'.format(num))

    print('Quantity of {0} = {1} items'.format(item, itemDict['Quantity']))

    print('Cost of one {0} = £{1:.2f}'.format(item, itemDict['Cost']))

    print('Time to install {0} = {1:.2f} hours\n'.format(item, itemDict['Time'] / 60))

# Output material cost dictionary
def outputMaterialCostDictionary():

    for key, value in materialCost.items():

        print('{0} = {1}'.format(key, value))

        print('\n')

# Output summary dictionary
def outputSummaryDictionary(summaryD, month, totalV):

    outputSummaryItem1(['Month', month, '', '', ''])

    outputSummaryItem1(['Total', '', 'Total', 'Total', 'Total'])

    outputSummaryItem1(['Working', 'Item', 'Square metre', 'Number', 'Monthly'])

    outputSummaryItem1(['Costs', '', 'Purchased', 'Purchased', 'Value'])  

    outputSummaryItem2('Lawn', summaryD['Lawn'])

    outputSummaryItem2('Patio', summaryD['Patio'])

    outputSummaryItem3('Water Feature', summaryD['Water Feature'])

    outputSummaryItem4(totalV)

# Output summary dictionary item ver 1
def outputSummaryItem1(sList):
    print('|{0:^13}|{1:^13}|{2:^13}|{3:^13}|{4:^13}|'.format(sList[0], sList[1], sList[2], sList[3], sList[4]))

# Output summary dictionary item ver 2
def outputSummaryItem2(name, item):
    print('|{0:^13}|{1:^13}|{2:13.2f}|{3:^13}|{4:13.2f}|'.format('', name, item['Quantity'], '', item['Value']))

# Output summary dictionary item ver 3
def outputSummaryItem3(name, item):
    print('|{0:^13}|{1:^13}|{2:^13}|{3:13.0f}|{4:13.2f}|'.format('', name, '', item['Quantity'], item['Value']))

# Output summary dictionary item ver 4
def outputSummaryItem4(totalValue):
    print('|{0:^13}|{1:^13}|{2:^13}|{3:^13}|{4:13.2f}|'.format('Total', '', '', '', totalValue))




# 'File handling'

# Function to output file
def outputToFile():

    filename = input('Enter file name: ')

    file = open(filename, 'w')

    month = input('Enter month:' )

    print('Filename = {0}....Month = {1}\n'.format(filename, month))

    file.write('{0}\n'.format(month))

    s = '{0} {1} {2} {3}\n'.format(quote['Lawn']['Length'], quote['Lawn']['Width'], quote['Lawn']['Cost'], quote['Lawn']['Time'])
    file.write(s)
    s = '{0} {1} {2} {3}\n'.format(quote['Patio']['Length'], quote['Patio']['Width'], quote['Patio']['Cost'], quote['Patio']['Time'])
    file.write(s)
    s = '{0} {1} {2}\n'.format(quote['Water Feature']['Quantity'], quote['Water Feature']['Cost'], quote['Water Feature']['Time'])
    file.write(s)
    file.close()


# Update quotes to date file 
    file = open(QUOTES_TO_DATE_FILE, 'a')


    s = '{0} {1}\n'.format(month, filename)

    file.write(s)
    file.close()

# Function to input quote from file where file name is not known
def inputQuoteFromFile1():

    filename = input('Enter name for input file: ')

    inputQuoteFromFile2(filename)


# Function to input quote from file when file IS known
def inputQuoteFromFile2(filename):

    file = open(filename, 'r')

    text = file.read()

    list1 = text.split()

    file.close()

# Process the data (ignore first item which is the month)
##declare 'quote' dict as global (this might mean this code is within function)
    global quote

    subDictionary = {'Length' : float(list1[1]), 'Width' : float(list1[2]), 'Cost' : float(list1[3]), 'Time' : float(list1[4])}

    quote['Lawn'] = subDictionary

    subDictionary = {'Length' : float(list1[5]), 'Width' : float(list1[6]), 'Cost' : float(list1[7]), 'Time' : float(list1[8])}

    quote['Patio'] = subDictionary

    subDictionary = {'Quantity' : float(list1[9]), 'Cost' : float(list1[10]), 'Time' : float(list1[11])}

    quote['Water Feature'] = subDictionary

    file.close()



# 'Menu options'

# Function to allow preperation of a new quote
def prepareANewQuote():
    itemInput()

    calculateItemCosts()

    workingCost()

    outputToFile()

# Function to load new material costs
def loadNewMaterialCosts():
    filename = input('Enter filename: ')

    file = open(filename, 'r')

    text = file.read()

    file.close()

    newMaterialCosts = text.split()

# Assign costs to material cost dictionary
    index = 0

    for key in materialCost.keys():

        materialCost['Key'] = float(newMaterialCosts['index'])

        index = index + 1

# Output new material costs # NOTE MAY NEED TO BE INDENTED FURTHER
    outputMaterialCostDictionary()
# Function to view and load existing quote
def viewExistingQuote():
    inputQuoteFromFile1()

    outputItems()

    workingCost()
# Function to generate monthly report summary
def monthlyReport():
    file = open(QUOTES_TO_DATE_FILE, 'r')

    text = file.read()

    file.close()

    quotes = text.split()

    month = input('Enter month: ')

    summary = {'Lawn':{'Quantity' : 0.0, 'Value' : 0.0}, 'Patio' :{'Quantity' : 0.0, 'Value' : 0.0}, 'Water Feature' :{'Quantity' : 0.0, 'Value' : 0.0}}
# Loop through quotes selecting those referencing the appropriate month and
#store the data in summary dictionary
    index = 0

    while True:

        if quotes[index] == month:

            inputQuotesFromFile2(quotes[index+1])    

            summary['Lawn']['Quantity'] = summary['Lawn']['Quantity'] + quote['Lawn']['Width'] * quote['Lawn']['Length']

            summary['Lawn']['Value'] = summary['Lawn']['Value'] + quote ['Lawn']['Cost']

            summary['Patio']['Quantity'] = summary['Patio']['Quantity'] + quote['Patio']['Width'] * quote['Patio']['Length']

            summary['Patio']['Value'] = summary['Patio']['Value'] + quote['Patio']['Cost']

            summary['Water Feature']['Quantity'] = summary['Water Feature']['Quantity'] + quote['Water Feature']['Quantity']

            summary['Water Feature']['Value'] = summary['Water Feature']['Value'] + quote['Water Feature']['Cost']

            index = index + 2

        if (index >= len(quotes)):

            break

        totalValue = summary['Lawn']['Value'] + summary['Patio']['Value'] + summary['Water Feature']['Value']

        outputSummaryDictionary(summary, month, totalValue)         



# 'Main' (initialisation)

# Top level function
def start():
    while True :

        print('Select one of following options')

        print('(1) Prepare new quote')

        print('(2) Load new cost data')

        print('(3) Load and view existing quote')

        print('(4) Generate monthly report summary')

        print('(5) Exit')

        selection = int(input())

        if selection == 1:

            prepareANewQuote()

        elif selection == 2:

            loadNewMaterialCosts()

        elif selection == 3:

            viewExistingQuote()

        elif selection == 4:

            monthlyReport()

        elif selection == 5:

            quit()

        else:

            print('Error unrecognised command')

# Start
start()
```

Comment: Use return instead of quit()?

Comment: Please post only relevant code. Also, what exactly is not working about this?

Comment: I see 2 `while` loops. Can you be a bit more specific?

Comment: Please never add long code samples, humans are really lazy beings and don't really want to read much, limit your code to describe the problem just precisely and nothing else. Keep it as concise as you can without loosing quality and clarity.

Comment: Apologies for the code length and 'while loop info', there is indeed two loops and I am referring to the first (I have included the 'header comment found above it in my description in terms of location) I defined my problem in the title 'unable to break infinite loop' but in future I will include reference in my description also to allow easier understanding, also I will provide a separate 'code window' highlighting the code that is (most likely at least) the code that needs fixing, I included the full code as sometimes the problem can actually be down to a separate part of the program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`index` never gets modified if `quotes[index]` does not equal `month`, so the code will keep checking the same value over and over again and never proceed.

You should unindent that assignment of `index` by one level. But really this is not an appropriate use of a while loop; you should use `for` to iterate over `quotes`:

```
for quote in quotes:
```

(Also note there are two while loops in this code; and actually *far* too much use of global.)